# Extracting unique values to lastrow of another table in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table (Sheet2) with a list of unique project IDs, this list is based on an advanced filter, and is updated regularly, adding new projects, while a lot of the old projects still appear on the list.

I have another table (Sheet1), where unique projects (that exist in Table A, but not in table B) have to be copied to the last row(+1) of the table. Users will then input information about the projects, so it is important that the information already in the table does not shift around when new projects are loaded.

I have this code, and on the surface it does the job. But i think it may a bit clunky, and users have experienced that when the macro is run, sometimes duplicates are added to table B. From the code, I don't see how this is possible, and i haven't been able to replicate it.

Can anyone take a look at the code and see if there's an issue? Or think of a simpler way to do what I'm looking for? I am new to VBA, and the code I've written has been lifted and adapted from elsewhere through trial and error, so I'm having a hard time figuring out if theres something wrong with it :-)

Project IDs are in column A, and I'm trying to copy values A:D from Sheet2 to Sheet1

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Projecs()

   Dim Source As Long
   Dim Dest As Long
   Dim Count As Long

   Source = 1
   Dest = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

   Do Until Sheet2.Cells(Source, "A") = ""
      If Sheet1.Range("A:A").Find(what:=Sheet2.Cells(Source, "A"), lookat:=xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
         Dest = Dest + 1
         Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(Dest, "A"), Sheet1.Cells(Dest, "D")).Value = _
            Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(Source, "A"), Sheet2.Cells(Source, "D")).Value
         Count = Count + 1
      End If
      Source = Source + 1
   Loop

   MsgBox "Copied " & Count & " projects to production"

End Sub
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are the ID's numeric or alpha-numeric ? Trailing spaces can be the reason for seemingly identical strings not to match, especially as you have lookat:=xlWhole

Comment: Congrats on the first question here! You are talking about Sheet1 & Sheet2 and about Table A and Table B, it's a little bit confusing. Is "Table A" a table in Sheet2 and "Table B" - a table in Sheet1? If so, I guess it would be better to keep the same names, like "(that exist in table from Sheet2, but not in table from Sheet1)"